# Integromat Scenario: One-shot module after iterating through a loop

Tags: zapier, make.com

I have created a scenario where I iterate through multiple modules with an array of data. This works fine.

After this completes, I want to run a module once before the scenario completes.

How do I add a module that won't get called in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to achieve this,

- Use Router to Create a new Route that will be triggered after the
  first route is complete
- Trigger new Scenario via Webhooks after you are done with the
  scenario
- If you are working with array, then using Array Aggregator or other
  Aggregators will allow you to first complete the iteration and then
  trigger the module you want to use

I am not sure exactly what you want to do after the iteration is complete, but setting the scenarios as displayed in the screenshot below should help you get started on this,

**Using Router**

For this you can create a router, the upper hand of the router is always executed first, so the iterator and other operations will be done there. After which, the next hand/route will be executed which will be the module you want to trigger at last.

[image]

However, If you want to pass some values from the first hand/route to the last one then you will need to set a variable and fetch it on the second route. See details here : https://www.integromat.com/en/help/converger

**Using Aggregator Module**

You can either use Array, Text or Numeric Aggregator to aggregate all the iteration operations and then trigger the module that you want to use at last.

[image]

As far as my knowledge goes, there is no Integromat default modules that can be configured before the scenario ends. We can leverage the Integromat API in future that is currently in development to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I found a filter to be the most easy way of doing this. Essentially chekcing if this bundle position is equal to the total number of bundles!

[image]

Comment: This is what I do!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in doing something on the last iteration only, you can use a filter to check if the current bundle is equal to the total number of bundles
[last bundle filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D18ke.png)

They won't let me paste pics *sigh*